# What are the bitmasks returned from AllocColorPlanes and AllocColorCells used for?

Tags: x11, xlib, xcb

I cannot get my head around what is the exact meaning of `AllocColorPlanes` and `AllocColorCells` requests. I get that they allocate colors, to which I then refer to using pixel values and I understand what a plane mask in general terms is, as described in the Glossary section of the documentation. What I do not understand is why are plane masks returned when allocating colors? I tried to find the answer in the X protocol documentation, the Xlib documentation, various man pages and code using XCB/Xlib, but none provided a meaningful answer.